# Module file was created for incompatible target x86_64-apple-macosx10.10

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I was trying to run the sample code from Apple's website, [Adding-Content-to-Apple-Music](https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2017/Interacting-with-Apple-Music-Content.zip), which shows how to interact with Apple Music Content.

Then it turned out to be a problem of dealing with JWT(JSON Web Token), and the current available libraries of JWT in Objective-C and Swift are at [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/).

But only vapor / jwt can sign with ES256, which Apple Music requires. I cloned the code from GitHub, "swift build" the library, and imported it into the project. However, I get this error on the line `import JWT` in my code:

Module file was created for incompatible target x86_64-apple-macosx10.10

What does this mean? Can I only use the library in macOS?

update: the jwt module works in vapor, and I think I can get the JWT successfully.

But when I do this in terminal :

[image]

just like the apple document says:

> "curl -v -H 'Authorization: Bearer [developer token]' "https
>   ://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/us/songs/203709340""

I got a http status code 500.....

Is it my fault or Apple's Server's??

Help me please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to use anther library in Python which name is jwcrypto.(pip install jwcrypto  to get it)
Python code:

```
from jwcrypto import jwt,jwk
import time
currentTime = time.time()
iat = int(currentTime)
exp = iat + 10000000
p8Data = open('AuthKey_myP8file.p8')
privateKey = p8Data.read()
key = jwk.JWK(generate='EC', curve='P-256')
key.import_from_pem(data=privateKey)
Token = jwt.JWT(header={'alg':'ES256', 'kid':'myKid'},claims={'iss':'myIss','iat':iat,'exp': exp })
Token.make_signed_token(key)
t = Token.serialize()// t is the Developer Token!!
```

Finally I got http status code 200, and the response! The picture is here:https://i.stack.imgur.com/67rHy.jpg